# xtext and xtend « punctuation mark, how do I get it?

Tags: xtext, xtend

I'm trying to add these punctuation mark things to XTend to define my generator for a custom language written in XText.  I'm getting very sick of copy/pasting the « quotation/punctuation mark all over the place.  Originally I copied it from one of their examples.

How in the world do I TYPE this mark?  I'm in the eclipse IDE... any help would be great, I've searched all over the web for this.

Comment: OK I found it.  This was totally non obvious and took me alot of cross referencing for the search, so I think it might be useful to others.  On windows you need to hit ALT+0187, etc.  like in the following link: https://typefacts.com/en/articles/keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, there should be a pretty simple shortcut to type it. Maybe Ctrl+< or just typing << or something like that. It's been a while since I've used it, but I definitely didn't have to copy-and-paste or enter unicode code points by hand.

Comment: In the Eclipse Xtend editor, you can simply use content assist to get these. And yes, it's mapped to a shortcut, too.

Answer (score 1):

Actually with Eclipse I'm finding that CTRL+SHIFT+< is what works.  This is with Eclipse Oxygen, maybe you're on another version.

Answer (score 0):

within eclipse you can use `Crtl+Space` or `Crtl+<` within a Rich String (`''''''`) to get the Guillemets